# How do you set the value of an input field by complex selector?

Tags: perl, browser-automation

- [WWW::Mechanize::Chrome](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize::Chrome) 0.10
- Iridium 2017.11 in a headed desktop session

I want to set the value of a certain **formless** input field.

```
my $field = $w->selector('tr.edit td[data-attribute="name"] input', single => 1);
```

finds it.

```
$field->attributes->{value} = 'test';
```

has no apparent effect.

Both

```
$w->field($field => 'test');
```

and

```
$w->field('tr.edit td[data-attribute="name"] input' => 'test');
```

error out with `No elements found for form number 1`.

Comment: I use a line of JS to do that.

Comment: You can try something like `$w->driver->send_message('DOM.setAttributeValue', nodeId => 0+$field->nodeId, name => 'value', value => "test" )->get` as per https://metacpan.org/source/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Chrome-0.10/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Chrome.pm#L3137

Comment: @daxim, any update on this?

Answer (score 5):

When I ran into this problem, I would just use the `eval` method and let Javascript (or jQuery if it's loaded in the page) take care of selecting and setting values. For me it was mostly selecting drop-downs, where the Angular application on the page required a *change* or *click* event.

```
$mech->eval( q{$(tr.edit td[data-attribute="name"] input).val('test')} );
```

If there is no jQuery I am sure your Google fu will help you out.

Answer (score 3):

You maybe able to use something like below

```
$w->driver->send_message('DOM.setAttributeValue', nodeId => 0+$field->nodeId, name => 'value', value => "test" )->get
```

Reference from the actual source code

https://metacpan.org/source/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Chrome-0.10/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Chrome.pm#L3137